# ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED firing like crazy

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-appwidget, battery

Okay, so I'm working on an AppWidget that checks the battery level and displays it on a TextView. My code looks like this:

```
public class BattWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

private RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews("com.nickavv.cleanwidgets", R.layout.battlayout);

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetIds[]) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(this,new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    Log.d("onReceive", "Received intent " + intent);
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)) {
        Integer level = intent.getIntExtra("level", -1);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.batteryText, level+"%");
        AppWidgetManager myAWM = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context, AirWidget.class);
        onUpdate(context, myAWM, myAWM.getAppWidgetIds(cn));
    }
}
}
```

And I'm getting concerned because as soon as I drop the widget onto my homescreen it begins firing off about 100 of those Log calls a second, saying it's receiving ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED. Isn't this only supposed to be broadcast for each percent decrease? It actually caused my entire launcher to lag, I had to uninstall it. That can't be right.

Comment: Don't really know anything about this but is it worth setting up a service to monitor the battery and feed that back to the widgit at a predefined interval?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> My code looks like this:

You cannot register a `BroadcastReceiver` from another `BroadcastReceiver` and get reliable results. Android will terminate your process, because it doesn't think anything is running. The only way to listen for `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` will be to register that receiver from an activity or a service.

> Isn't this only supposed to be broadcast for each percent decrease?

Where do you see that documented? AFAIK, `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` will be broadcast whenever the hardware feels like it. Also, bear in mind that other data changes within that `Intent`, such as temperature.

If you want to implement this app widget, do not register for `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` the way you are. Instead:

- Allow the user to choose a polling period via a `SharedPreference` (e.g., once a minute, once every 15 mintues)
- Use `AlarmManager` to give you control on that polling period via a `getBroadcast()` `PendingIntent`
- In that `BroadcastReceiver`, call `registerReceiver()` for `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` **but with a `null` BroadcastReceiver**, as this will return to you the last `Intent` that was broadcast for that action (note: you will still need to use `getApplicationContext()` for this)
- Use `AppWidgetManager` to update your app widget instances with the battery level pulled out of the `Intent` you retrieved in the preceding step (note: if you are setting them all to be the same, you do not need to iterate over the IDs -- use the `updateAppWidget()` that takes a `ComponentName` as a parameter)

This has several advantages:

1. You do not care how often `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` is broadcast
2. The user gets to control how much battery you consume by doing these checks (should be negligible if you keep the polling period to a minute or more)
3. Your process can be safely terminated in between polls, thereby making it less likely that users will attack you with task killers and semi-permanently mess up your app

Comment: That can't be the best way to go about this. I've seen plenty of closed-source battery widgets that update their information as soon as a change occurs (BattStatt is a good example). I've never seen one that offers the user an update interval. Battery level widgets are supposed to always be accurate.

Comment: @Nick: "That can't be the best way to go about this" -- you are entitled to your opinion. "I've seen plenty of closed-source battery widgets that update their information as soon as a change occurs" -- which they do by wasting a bunch of RAM by keeping a service in memory all of the time. Users think that developers who do this are idiots, why is why task killers are so popular and the OS has to proactively kill such services off.

Comment: @Nick: "Battery level widgets are supposed to always be accurate" -- since the battery level does not change particularly frequently, a polling architecture can be more than sufficiently accurate, while avoiding the RAM hit and inherent unreliability of keeping a service around all the time.

Comment: Alright, you've got me convinced. Now, you say to register ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED in "that" BroadcastReceiver. Would that be the onReceive function of my AppWidgetProvider? Because I tried that and it doesn't seem to be registering at all.

Comment: @Nick: "Would that be the onReceive function of my AppWidgetProvider?" -- no, it would be in a `BroadcastReceiver` you set up to receive alarms from `AlarmManager`. When the alarm event occurs based on your polling period, you get the then-current battery level via `registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you tell me why it's important to use getApplicationContext()? You indicated that in your third bullet point above. The onReceive method in my BroadcastReceiver has a context in its list of parameters. I've used it directly when registering my receiver for ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED (in the manner that you advised). I've also used context.getApplicationContext(). etc. etc. In my testing I see no difference in behaviour. Thanks.

Comment: @UpLate: "Can you tell me why it's important to use getApplicationContext()?" -- it used to crash when you tried using `registerRecevier()` directly using the passed-in `Context` to `onReceive()`, saying that registering a receiver with this `Context` was not allowed, even though we were not actually registering a receiver. Perhaps they relaxed that restriction in the past couple of years. Still, I would assume that at least Android 2.x has the restriction.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ahhhhh!! Right you are. 1st gen Nexus 7, Android 4.3, with or without getApplicationContext(), behaviour is the same. Nexus One, Android 2.3.6, with getApplicationContext() and all's well. Without getApplicationContext() causes a crash. I'm supporting Gingerbread devices so this little tidbit has been valuable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your onUpdate is registering its own class as receiver for the batteryinfo intent. This intent is then immediately triggered for the first info.
Your onReceive is calling your onUpdate again. We call this a loop. Hence the 100 logs a second ...