# About sticky intent ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using this code:

```
Intent i = getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

and as far as I understand `i` should be null if ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED didn't occur, but it is never null and always returns me the same data.
It worked fine when I used a broadcast receiver. Do I need to delete the Intent after receiving it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as you register sticky intents will always deliver you last broadcasted data. So that is the reason you are always recieving data

Comment: so I need to comapre the battery level for example to see if a new Intent was bradcasted?

Comment: this will only happen the first time you register. Later on you will recieve as soon as broadcast is done

Comment: but I dont use a Receiver. I want to check, lets say, every 60 seconds if a occured since the last check.

Comment: why would you want that when as soon as battery is changed you get a callback.

Comment: because of that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624882/action-battery-changed-firing-like-crazy what do you think about it? what would you say is the better solution?

Comment: it depends on what your app does? what is the use case?

Answer (score 1):

Sticky=property of adhering
result=which intent adhered with os called sticky intent

Normally you send broadcast a receiver using sendBroadcast(Intent)  But When you are calling this method sendStickyBroadcast(Intent)  it means that A broadcast Intent can be specified to be sticky in which case it will be **retained** by the system after it has been sent. But by default Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED intent is sticky.

read the full post here http://iphoidtech.com/uncategorized/what-is-stcky-intent/