# Implementing a battery widget with alarmservice?

Tags: android, service

This question got me to think of the way I was writing my battery widget.

[ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED firing like crazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624882/action-battery-changed-firing-like-crazy)

I'm concerned with the power usage. I saw how frequent ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED gets fired. Even if you check if the battery level actually changed before you perform the update operation, it still looks a little expensive.

So, which of either listening to ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED in service or setting alarmservice for like every 5min - 10min to update the widget sound more efficient?

The widget would just be switching ImageView source according to battery level and updating a TextView. Though might consider drawing the text into the image using Bitmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not care about ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED events, just use `Alarm` to check the battery status every 5-10 minutes, that is pretty much enough for your purpose.

On the other hand, do you seriously think someone needs another battery widget in 2013 ?

Comment: This is a practice. I'm gonna try with Alarm approach.

Answer (score 0):

That depends entirely on if the battery events are raised more frequently than the alarm.
If you're making an app widget make sure you're not updating when not visible.

I made a live wallpaper based on battery level and see no adverse affects of using the battery changed events

Comment: On my device, it seems to be getting called like every 25 sec with the screen on. It's checking very frequently.